# Java "try-catch" an Object / Object Array types

Tags: java, arrays

Hello i'm trying to do a "cheap" learnOcaml model for Java and I'm trying to catch any type the function f() could catch but I have a problem with Object type when he is declared as "Not array type" I'm getting that error while compiling:

```
Tester.java:45: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Object[]
                                        Object[] res_string = f();
                                                               ^
Tester.java:54: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Object[]
                                        Object[] res_char = f();
                                                             ^
2 errors
```

I'm sure it's because Object type cannot be converted that way into Object[] type so I tried to try catch to handle that error but it's wrong so can someone helps me with that problem here is my code.

```
static String f() 
{
     String res = "2";
     return res;
}

public static void main (String args [])
        {
                Boolean isArray = f().getClass().isArray();
                if(!isArray)
                {
                        System.out.println(f());
                }
                else
                {
                      Object[] res_string = f();
                      for(int i=0; i<res_string.length; i++)
                      {
                             System.out.print(res_string[i]);
                      } 
                }
        }
```

Comment: It's a compilation errors. Exceptions are a runtime thing. You cannot "catch" compilation _errors_.

Comment: The return type of a method is determined at compile time, so this code does not make much sense. You should explain in more detail what you are really trying to accomplish

Comment: I want to be able to insert the static f() function as the "student code" and print it whatever type he his writting in his code

Answer (score 0):

Your error is a *compile time error* - your code doesn't make sense. There is a fundamental difference between compile time errors, which occur even before you run anything (in fact, you can't run anything - you don't get class files), and runtime errors, which result when your code is compiled, you run it, and then something occurs at runtime that makes the code throw an exception.

exceptions (and therefore, `try`/`catch`) apply to runtime errors **only**.

You seem to misunderstand what "converted" means in the error:

> error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Object[]

As is somewhat obvious from the code, the line `Object[] res_string = f();` **would not actually be executed** if you tried to run this code somehow (you can't, as it won't compile, but let's say hypothetically this code would compile). After all, the `isArray` boolean value is `false`, so the `else` block won't trigger.

Nevertheless, you get this error, because that line of code doesn't make sense. And not for the reason you think!

If you replace your `f` method with:

```
static Object f() {
  return new Object[10];
}
```

It **still** will not compile, even though now clearly what `f()`  returns can easily be 'converted' to an object array - it already *is* an object array.

The problem isn't with the runtime at all. It's a simple type mismatch: The compiler notes that the specification of the `f()` method declares that it is allowed to return any value whose type is `Object` (every object fulfills that requirement, as does `null`).

Sure, **right now**, it always returns an object array, but those signatures are in part also about: Yeah okay but maybe later I'll change just the code within the `f()` method and I don't want any other code to then all of a sudden start breaking.

Your code makes no sense in general, but the one-liner fix is that you want to inject an operation: "Hey, compiler, please generate code that CHECKS that the value returned by `f()` is an `Object[]` array. If it is, great, do nothing and let the code continue, if it is not, throw a `ClassCastException`. With that injected, the *compiler* is now fine with it (hey, if it isn't, at runtime, you get an exception, that's fine). You do this with a cast: `Object[] o = (Object[]) f();`.

Which still won't compile, because the compiler knows there is no point trying to cast an expression of type `String` to `Object[]`, as it **can never** be true. Why would the compiler compile code it knows cannot possibly execute, ever? Instead it'll tell you that you're confused.

Comment: Yes but how can I do it that way I want to insert the "student code" as the function f() with any possible type (int string int[] string [] etc... ) And print it with my main. As he can write String f() int f() etc...

Comment: @GGH Simply define return type as `Object` and assign to `Object`? Object references can hold any type (even arrays).

Comment: @GGH You can't use try/catch to fix compilation errors. What you want is very complicated, would involve learning about some/all of java AST parsers, the compilation API, classloading mechanism, and have you thought about how to deal with students that write `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("FORMAT C:");` ?